# node-schedule not working with send at specific date rule

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to setup an email reminder using Node-schedule and nodemailer.

Basically my application needs to send two emails... one immediately when the module is called, and one at a specific date.

For now I just chose a random date for testing, but I am not able to receive the scheduled mail.

I can confirm that the emails work just fine as I am able to receive them when sent instantly, the date specified node scheduler does not work however.

Just FYI:
I tested to make sure my server is running at the same time as I am, and I am inputing 24hour date format.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

module.exports = function (jobData) {
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport
        ('smtps://emailname%40gmail.com:somepassword@smtp.gmail.com');

function callTransporter(emailData) {
    smtpTransport.sendMail(emailData, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    });
}

function interviewReminderEmail(emailData) {
    var mailOptions = {
        from: '"Job Seeker" <donotreply@fdsfsdf.com>',
        to: 'someperson@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Interview coming up! ✔',
        text: 'some message',
        html: '<b>blablabla</b>'
    };

    var interviewDate = new Date(2016, 4, 30, 15, 30, 0);

    //region of code where I setup scheduled email. 
    // I get no errors, however it is not sending an email either.
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob(interviewDate, function () {
        console.log('Sending interview reminder Email.');
        callTransporter(mailOptions);
    });
}

interviewReminderEmail(jobData);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out, the month of April is 3 because January starts at 0. doh!